# EC2 Linux AMI with ffmpeg (no yasm?)

Tags: amazon-ec2, ffmpeg

I'm running a Basic 64-bit Amazon Linux AMI 2011.09 (AMI Id: ami-953b06e1) and I want to install ffmpeg into it so I can use it convert video.

These are the commands I run after firing up a new instance:

```
sudo -i
yum update
yum install gcc
yum install gcc-c++
yum install make
```

Then for yasm I get "No package yasm available." so I do this:

```
cd /usr/local/src/
wget http://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/releases/yasm-0.7.0.tar.gz
tar zfvx yasm-0.7.0.tar.gz
cd yasm-0.7.0
./configure && make && make install
```

Followed by

```
yum install git
yum install subversion
yum install check-devel
yum groupinstall "Development Tools" -y
```

I'm trying to follow the instructions from http://pitchpublish.com/?p=158 and this is the point where it all fails.

```
cd /usr/local/src
wget http://webm.googlecode.com/files/libvpx-v0.9.6.tar.bz2
tar -xvf libvpx-v0.9.6.tar.bz2
cd libvpx-v0.9.6
./configure
make
make install
```

But at the point that I run `./configure` it runs a few lines then "Neither yasm nor nasm have been found". Despite the fact that when I ran `./configure` when setting up yasm there were no errors.

As you can see setting all this up confuses me, a lot. At the end of the day I want a PHP environment in which I can convert video to h264, webm, and get some video screenshots.

Comment: The new versions of Amazon's Linux are fully compatible with EPEL, and include that repository as well (although disabled). Yasm is available in EPEL: `yum --enablerepo=epel install yasm`. Chances are you are missing the `yasm-devel` package - which you would need if you are compiling other code against it.

Comment: The yasm in that repo is version 0.7. When I come to compile x264 I get an error saying I need v1 minimum - with a command to configure --disable-asm. Which works.
Then I configure ffmpeg and everything runs fine.
But, when I check for ffmpeg existence with PHP `trim(shell_exec('type -P ffmpeg'))` it states it's not available.

Can anyone recommend an article I can read so I can get my head around the concept of where all these things should be installed, dependencies, etc?

Comment: AWS actually provides a service for video transcoding that you may want to check out: http://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/